# Изменение данных таблицы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, у нас есть таблица:

```
<table id="table_one" class="info">
<thead>
<tr class="row-one">
<th class="column-1">Название.</th>
<th class="column-2">Стоимость.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="row">
<td class="column-1"><a href="http://site1.ru/" target="_blank">Site1</a>.</td>
<td class="column-2">$1.</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
<td class="column-1"><a href="http://site2.ru/" target="_blank">Site2</a>.</td>
<td class="column-2">$2.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Так вот, необходимо произвести некоторые операции с этой таблицей. По умолчанию естественно показываются Site1 и Site2 у первых двух строк таблицы, но нужно нажатием на ссылку-переключатель, чтобы показывалось http://site1.ru/ и http://site2.ru/ соответственно.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нихрена непонятно, делал на бум:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>

<script>

$( function(){
    $('td.column-1 a').click( function(){
        this.innerHTML = this.href;

        return false;
    })
});

</script>

<table id="table_one" class="info" border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr class="row-one">
        <th class="column-1">Название.</th>
        <th class="column-2">Стоимость.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="column-1"><a href="http://site1.ru/" target="_blank">Site1</a>.</td>
            <td class="column-2">$1.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="column-1"><a href="http://site2.ru/" target="_blank">Site2</a>.</td>
            <td class="column-2">$2.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```